# Как сделать консольное приложение, которое бесконечно работает в фоне и реагирует на события?

Tags: c#, .net

Только зацикливанием main можно решить данную задачу или есть более красивое решение?

Comment: Быть может имеет смысл подумать в сторону сервисов?

Comment: На какие именно события?

Comment: @PashaPash, подключение/отключение внешних дисков.

Comment: Для таких целей лучше все таки сервис, вот и статья на тему того как https://habrahabr.ru/post/102826/

Comment: Лень писать ответ - поэтому набросаю сюда ключевых слов. *"RegisterDeviceNotification, WM_DEVICECHANGE, невидимая форма, Application.Run()"*.

Comment: @PavelMayorov ну кстати, да, можно еще в трей форму свернуть, что-то я не подумал сразу =)

Comment: @rdorn, еще, можно очень просто и быстро делать сервисы с помощью [TopShelf](http://www.christophdebaene.com/blog/2011/03/16/create-a-net-windows-service-in-5-steps-with-topshelf/).

Comment: @rdorn, в чем преимущество  TopShelf ?

Comment: Это скорее к @AndreyK. вопрос, но по я так понимаю, что преимущество в том, что часть работы уже сделана, остается только прикрутить нужные декорации и специфический функционал.

Comment: @iluxa1810, без _TopShelf_ - геморрой, а с _TopShelf_ - 3 строчки. Отлаживать просто. Делаешь как консольное приложение, потом передаешь параметр (в запуске из командной строки), и оно запускается как служба. Это не альтернатива винсервису, а тот же винсервис. Наизусть не помню, как именно пользоваться, но примерно так. Короче, это супер штука, когда нужно сделать винсервис.

Answer (score 7):

Суть приложения — это выполнение функции Main, пока это приложение должно работать. Соответственно, если приложение должно работать вечно, то не выходить из метода Main — это единственное верное и абсолютно естественное решение.

Пусть вас не обманывают разные платформы вроде Windows.Forms — в конечном счёте ваш код уходит корнем в метод Main в .NET, который уходит корнем во входной адрес в заголовке исполняемого файла. Когда функция завершает выполнение, ось считает процесс выполнившимся.

С точки зрения реализации, конечно, не надо делать `while (true) Thread.Sleep(1)`, вместо это следует по-нормальному дожидаться событий, на которые приложение должно реагировать. Например, если приложение должно реагировать на ввод в консоль, то в цикле можно сделать чтение `Console.ReadLine()` — эта функция остановит выполнение без пожирания процессорного времени и вернёт строку тогда, когда она есть.

Правда в винде "вечно работающие приложения" обычно делают службами. Служба регистрируется в системном списке служб, получает средства для управления выполнения пользователем, ось следит за запуском и работой службы и т. п. Консоль удобна разве что для отладки, потому что можно выводить журнал сразу в консоль для наглядности. Если приложение должно тесно взаимодействовать с пользователем, ещё можно сделать иконку в области уведомлений.

Answer (score 1):

Консольное приложение не может работать в ФОНЕ. Консоль - это stdin, stdout и stderr. ЛЮБОЕ приложение работающее в фоне обязано отключить эти стандартные файлы.

Такое приложение, в linux терминологии, называется "демоном". На виндовозном языке - "сервис".

Существуют строгие правила написания демонов. Например, как они должны отключаться от консоли. Эти правила изложены во многих местах. Например здесь:

http://citforum.ru/programming/unix/daemons/

Любой демон находится в состоянии ожидания, до тех пор, пока не происходит некоторое событие. Ну, например:

- Демон получил сигнал SIGHUP
- Демон получил извещение от inotify
- Пришло сообщение из канала или очереди сообщений
  ...

Comment: В вопросе спрашивается, очевидно, о Windows, а вы в вашем ответе рассказываете о программировании юниксовских daemon'ов.

Comment: @VladD, из вопроса не вытекает платформа.

Comment: @ixSci: Не, ну формально конечно не вытекает. Но в реальной жизни что-то я не видел среди юниксоидов радостного хайпа по поводу C#, так что в ответе не хватает фразы «В том невероятном случае, если ваша целевая платформа — Linux, ...».

Comment: _по поводу C#_  Перечитал вопрос ещё раз, но не увидел там слов "C#" или "Windows".  Может не туда смотрю?

Писать демона на C# - это круто! :-) Можно, наверное, на РНР попробовать... Может, всё-таки, шурупы - закручивать, а гвозди - забивать ?

Comment: @Сергей, смотрите какие теги у вопроса(голубые прямоугольники в вопросе)

Comment: Или я смотрю не туда, или мы вообще о разном говорим! :-(

Я вижу в заголовке:

"Как сделать консольное приложение, которое бесконечно работает в фоне и реагирует на события?"

О каких голубых прямоугольниках вы говорите? Можно скриншот глянуть, как это у Вас выглядит ?

Comment: А!!!! Увидел, наконец!  Ладно, Вы правы - вопрос действительно по C#...

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых работающее в фоне приложение конечно должно быть сервисом (Windows Service). Но полезно реализовать двоякий режим -- чтобы можно было также запустить с командной строки -- нужно для проверок и отладки.

Во-вторых, нужен шедулер (scheduler) -- часть программы которая отвечает за вызов задач (tasks, jobs) по расписанию или по внешним событиям.
Шедулер лучше взять готовый (например, Quartz.net) -- чтобы не наступать снова на все те же самые грабли.